# Font awesome does not show its icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Been wondering for a few minutes why Font awesome icons did not appear into my application, but after writing this [ultra-simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p48ds2v0/1/), I see that they don't appear at all even with so little code.

I am just loading the CDN and inserting an icon like this:

```
<!-- Font awesome stylesheet -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x">This is a camera</i>
<i class="fa fa-icon-remove fa-2x" style="color: red;">This is an X</i>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the font-awesome library... http://jsfiddle.net/p48ds2v0/2/ Font-awesome is not included in bootstrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x">This is a camera</i>
<i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x" style="color: red;">This is an X</i>
```

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p48ds2v0/5/)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of errors.

1. No fontAwesome Lib
2. Mistyped icon class

**Solution:**

Add the link below to the space provided for external resource on fiddle

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

**Then change**

```
<i class="fa fa-icon-remove fa-2x" style="color: red;">This is an X</i>
```

**To**

```
<i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x" style="color: red;">This is an X</i>
```

**Note:** You don't need the word **icon** between **fa** and **remove**.

[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/p48ds2v0/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If using jsfiddle you have to add the following link under external resources:

//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Or use this in your head section:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nLsuknz/1/) updated.